# How do you make increment counter more readable?

Tags: javascript

I saw this code someone else wrote and was wondering how to make it more readable. I tried to separate the `++` to a separate line but the logic didn't work quite the same

```
if (map[s[l++]]++ === 0) {
    count++; 
  }
```

I tried to make it into this, but the logic below was wrong

```
  if (map[s[l+1]] === 0) {
    count++; 
    map[s[l+1]]++;
    l++;
  }
```

Comment: `l+1` and `l++` are not the same btw. Both increment `l` by one, however `l+1` doesn't set the value of `l` to the new value. Perhaps try `l=l+1`, but this seems more unreadable to me, so perhaps stick with `l++`

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (map[s[l++]]++ === 0) {
    count++; 
}

// is equal to

if (map[s[l]] === 0) {
  count++;
}
l++;
map[s[l]]++;
```

Comment: so the `l++` and `map[s[l]]++` has to be outside of `if` curly brackets?

Comment: @guest `map[s[l++]]++` will always increment the values no matter if the expression `map[s[l++]]++ === 0` is true

Comment: oic. interesting. tho i tried your code but it still didn't quite work